# Preference: OnClick directing towards social network

Tags: java, android

I created a Preference Activity where I put various Preference for Social Networks (Facebook, Twitter, Google+), I would like clicking on these preference you may be directed to the respective pages, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will open browser with given URL:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

If you want to open app, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: and if I want to open facebook app?

Comment: and if I want to give the user the option to choose whether to open the browser or the application of facebook?

Comment: Create a dialog with 2 buttons, one it will open website, other application.